# npm error: peerinvalid The package rxjs does not satisfy its siblings

Tags: angularjs, angular, npm, npm-install, package.json

Does anyone solved that problem?
I'm using angular latest version with systemjs (no angular-cli)
and got inspired from the quickstart of angular.

I really tried to change the version of things and their order, but did not helped at all.

What did I missed?

```
6035 error code EPEERINVALID
6036 error peerinvalid The package rxjs does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
6036 error peerinvalid Peer angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.21 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
6036 error peerinvalid Peer angular-in-memory-web-api@0.2.4 wants rxjs@^5.0.1
6036 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/http@2.4.7 wants rxjs@^5.0.1
6036 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/core@2.4.7 wants rxjs@^5.0.1
6036 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/router@3.4.7 wants rxjs@^5.0.1
```

package.json:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "chromedriver": "2.24.0",
    "connect-livereload": "~0.3.2",
    "grunt-angular-templatecache": "0.2.5",
    "grunt-cache-bust": "0.6.0",
    "grunt-cli": "0.1.13",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "1.0.2",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "0.14.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-icomoon-zip": "0.0.2",
    "grunt-karma": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-processhtml": "~0.3.2",
    "grunt-properties-reader": "0.1.3",
    "grunt-protractor-runner": "3.2.0",
    "grunt-serve": "0.1.6",
    "grunt-sync": "0.0.4",
    "ip": "1.1.3",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "jasmine-reporters": "2.0.0",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "1.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~0.5.5",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "3.4.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.13",
    "protractor": "3.3.0",
    "protractor-html-screenshot-reporter": "0.0.21",
    "protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter ": "0.0.6",
    "time-grunt": "1.3.0",
    "selenium-server-standalone-jar": "2.52.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.48",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~2.2.1",

    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~2.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",

    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.2.1",

    "rxjs": "5.0.1",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.21",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",


    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",

    "zone.js": "^0.7.4",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error clearly states that `angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.21` requires older version of `rxjs`. Try to update `angular2-in-memory-web-api` to the latest version which is actually shipped under new name `angular-in-memory-web-api`.

Comment: I updated angular-in-memory-web-api to the latest. Now getting this: error peerinvalid The package @angular/common does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
206 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/forms@2.4.7 wants @angular/common@2.4.7
206 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser@2.4.7 wants @angular/common@2.4.7
206 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.4.7 wants @angular/common@2.4.7
206 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-server@2.2.4 wants @angular/common@2.2.4
206 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/router@3.4.7 wants @angular/common@

Comment: @angular/common@2.2.4 => @angular/common@2.4.7

Comment: error peerinvalid The package @angular/common does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
206 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/forms@2.4.7 wants @angular/common@2.4.7
206 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser@2.4.7 wants @angular/common@2.4.7
206 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.4.7 wants @angular/common@2.4.7
206 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-server@2.2.4 wants @angular/common@2.2.4
206 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/router@3.4.7 wants @angular/common@2.4.7

Comment: all angular packages must have the same version, except router. @angular/platform-server@2.2.4 => @angular/platform-server@2.4.7

Comment: error peerinvalid Peer @angular/core@2.4.7 wants rxjs@^5.0.1
248 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/http@2.4.7 wants rxjs@^5.0.1
248 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/router@3.4.7 wants rxjs@^5.0.1
248 error peerinvalid Peer angular-in-memory-web-api@0.2.4 wants rxjs@^5.0.1
248 error peerinvalid Peer angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.21 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12

Comment: I have set all @angular to 2.4.7 version. Also change rxjs to 5.0.1

Comment: angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.21 should be removed, it is replaced by  angular-in-memory-web-api

Comment: I am doing: rm -rf node_modules,
npm cache clean. hope it will help